# Is it possible to expand elem to support a -> [[a]] -> Bool?

Tags: haskell

I have a polyomino problem that requires placing polyominos onto a board.
I am using the following type to support this.

```
type Block = (Int, Int)
type Polyomino = [Block]
type Board = [Polyomino]
```

Part of my solution is a function that checks if any blocks of a polyomino have already been placed in the board.

```
unPlaced :: Polyomino -> Int -> Int -> Board -> Bool
unPlaced _ _ _ [] = True
unPlaced ((a, b):cs) x y b = --check if in Board
```

(`x` and `y` are the offsets of the current polyomino)

I know I can use `elem` to check in each polyomino in the board like so

```
unPlaced ((a, b):cs) x y b:bs = if (((a+x),(b+y)) `elem` b) 
then False
else unPlaced ((a, b):cs) x y bs
```

but I’m unsure how to complete this solution since I cannot "refresh" my board after checking through every element of it.

I believe a function `a -> [[a]] -> Bool` will allow me to complete this, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a function with that signature easily by composing other functions, but there's more than one way to do it, with different behaviour, so which one will be useful to you depends on the behaviour you wish it to have.

One way to go about it is to elevate `elem`. If you look at the type of `elem`, it has this type:

```
Prelude> :t elem
elem :: (Eq a, Foldable t) => a -> t a -> Bool
```

So, one thing you can do is to elevate the first value, of type `a`, to a `Functor`, like this:

```
pelem :: (Applicative f, Eq (f a), Foldable t) => a -> t (f a) -> Bool
pelem = elem . pure
```

It may not do what you want it to do, though:

```
*Q49002862> pelem "foo" [["foo", "bar"],["baz"]]
False
*Q49002862> pelem "baz" [["foo", "bar"],["baz"]]
True
```

Notice that it elevates `"foo"` to `["foo"]`, and `"baz"` to `["baz"]`, so that only the last query returns `True`.

This may not be what you want, so alternatively, you can pull in `join` from `Control.Monad` and define `jelem` like this:

```
jelem :: (Foldable t, Eq a, Monad t) => a -> t (t a) -> Bool
jelem x = elem x . join
```

This returns `True` as long as it finds just one element in the flattened (*joined*) foldable container:

```
*Q49002862> jelem "foo" [["foo", "bar"],["baz"]]
True
*Q49002862> jelem "baz" [["foo", "bar"],["baz"]]
True
*Q49002862> jelem "qux" [["foo", "bar"],["baz"]]
False
```

I'm sure one can think up an implementation of the latter that has fewer restrictions (e.g. doesn't require `t` to be a `Monad`),  but that's what I could think up on short notice.

To be clear, the words `pelem` and `jelem` are some I made up right now. They don't mean anything - I just took the first letter of `pure` and `join`, respectively, and put them in front of `elem`.

Comment: I'd suggest `any . elem` instead of `elem x . join`. The former works for any `(Eq a, Foldable outer, Foldable inner) => outer (inner a)`.

Comment: This is a nice answer (+1) but I fear it is way over the current skill level of the OP. I mean, if the OP can not figure out how to test membership in a list-of-lists, they probably will not understand foldables, applicative, monads. Pointfree notation does not help, either.

Answer (score 2):

I will try to simplify the answer of Mark Seemann to the specific case which is being asked in the OP. The intent is to make it more accessible to beginners.

In the libraries, we find a function

```
elem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
```

but we want, instead

```
elem2 :: Eq a => a -> [[a]] -> Bool
```

As a silly tentative, we can try to use `elem` anyway:

```
elem2 :: Eq a => a -> [[a]] -> Bool
elem2 x xss = elem x xss
```

This will cause a type error, since `xss` is of type `[[a]]`, while `elem` expects a `[a]` for its second argument. However we can try to "convert" `xss` so that is becomes something of the right type. This requires a function of type `[[a]] -> [a]`.

The libraries do provide a function `concat :: [[a]] -> [a]`, which takes a list of lists and "flattens" their elements into a single list. In our case, this is the "conversion" we need: `x` belongs to the list-of-lists iff it belongs to the flattened list. Hence, we can use

```
elem2 :: Eq a => a -> [[a]] -> Bool
elem2 x xss = elem x (concat xss)
```

which is a working solution.

This can be further generalized, as Mark Seemann did, to general foldable monads (monadic `join` is a generalization of `concat` which only works on lists). He also wrote `elem2` using pointfree notation, making the code more compact, but the solution is the same one.